# Why isn't jest being installed with @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest?

Tags: lwc-jest

I'm working with a new project and tried to commit my first Lightning Web Component. I got this error:

```
ESLint: 7.30.0

Error: Error while loading rule 'jest/no-deprecated-functions':
Unable to detect Jest version - please ensure jest package is
installed, or otherwise set version explicitly
```

Poking around, I see that my `package.json` includes `"@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.14.0"` in `devDependencies` and looking at the `package.json` in `node_modules/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` and see that there's a line in `dependencies` for `"jest": "26.6.3"`. I do *not* see a `node_modules/jest` directory.

Just to be sure I perform `npm install` again, and nothing I've said above has changed.

Why isn't `jest` being installed with `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` when it's a dependency of it?

> Note: manually adding `jest` to my own `devDepencies` does remove the error.